# How To get records by checking relationship attributes in Laravel NeoEloquent

Tags: php, laravel-4, neo4j, eloquent

I am building an application in which I am using laravel with Neo4j using NeoEloquent driver.

Database schema is like

`(User)-[r:ADDED {status: 0}]->(Category)
(User)-[r:ADDED {status: 1}]->(Category)
(User)-[r:ADDED {status: 1}]->(Category)`

How can I get all the categories whose relationship status = 1 using NeoEloquent.
I know Cypher query for this is like

`Match (n:User)-[r:ADDED{status:1}]-(m:Category) return m`.

But I want this type of query using NeoEloquent.
Please help.

Comment: Did you take a look at this package? https://github.com/Vinelab/NeoEloquent

Comment: Yes, But there also I didnt found any method to get result by relationship or applying where condition to relationship.

Comment: for anyone loooking for a solution you might want to watch this: https://github.com/Vinelab/NeoEloquent/issues/75

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately fetching relations with attributes is still not supported by NeoEloquent, this feature is at the top of the list in the next release but no ETA set yet. PRs are highly appreciated in that regard!